# How do I move a post to another forum, like CV/stats?

Tags: support, deletion, migration, cross-posting

So yesterday I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187630/deriving-negentropy-getting-stuck), but I think that is might get more attention over at Stats/CV.

How do I move it, or ask someone to move it?

I ask because I was tempted to delete it completely and (try) to re-write it to make it more accessible to readers, since I can understand that at first glances it looks quite thick, (but it really isnt! ;-) )

I wanted to delete it originally and try and post a really really abridged version, so that I dont have a dupe, but figured to ask about moving it instead. The bad thing is that if I move it might not get some future attention here, but cest la vie I suppose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators on the site your question is *currently* on have the power to migrate it to any other site in the SE network.

Flag your post for moderator attention and fill the "other" textbox in with a short case for moving it to *(site of your choice)*. If it's clear even at a short glance that your question falls within the scope of the target site, the "short case" can consist of just a statement that you'd like to have it moved.

It's a good idea to make an account on the target first, and get it cross-associated with your MSE account before you ask for migration; that way you get to keep ownership of the question after it has moved.